# postgresql: оптимизация при сравнении одного поля с несколькими

Tags: sql, postgresql, оптимизация, оптимизация-запросов

есть такое условие в `where`:

```
value = t1.key and value <> t2.key
```

подскажите, а вообще можно ли как-то оптимизировать запросы с таким условием?

1. изменить само условие - просто выражение `(A = B) & (A != C)` кажется каким-то привлекательным
2. сформировать составные индексы, отличные от связки `(value, key)`

это скорее академический интерес, поскольку запрос после составления составного индекса и так работает быстро, но хотелось бы узнать, может как-то более правильно такие вещи делаются